# Oracle SQL Plus WITH Clause "invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

The database is running on Oracle Database 11g using SQL *Plus 11.2.  Are aggregate methods not allowed in a WITH clause or is WITH doing something magical?  This code tells me "most_expensive" is an invalid identifier.  Yet, a sub-query works with no issue.

```
WITH most_expensive AS (SELECT MAX (enrollment_cost) FROM Enrollments)
SELECT e.member_id
FROM Enrollments e
WHERE e.enrollment_cost = most_expensive;
```

Comment: You don't have a _column_ name `most_expensive` in your query - only a sub-query. But you _refer_ to a column of that name in your `where` clause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query factoring (with clauses) allows you to define temporary table aliases.
In your example most_expensive is going to reference a table object containing a single row with a single column.  You can use it anywhere in the query where you can use a table.
Now, if you create a table called t1 (with create table statment), give it one column and insert 1 row, you still won't be able to do "WHERE x = t1".
In other words, a subquery is not always the same as a table, and WITH clauses gives you something that behaves like tables, not like subqueries.

The following works though:

```
WITH most_expensive AS (SELECT MAX (enrollment_cost) FROM Enrollments)
SELECT member_id
FROM Enrollments e
WHERE e.enrollment_cost = (select * from most_expensive);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/6340

Comment: Thank you, your answer is helpful.  Though, what is a subquery returning then?  I assumed it was also just giving back a table with 1 row and 1.  It still helps in large queries, but I was hoping there was a way to keep a temporary variable to keep the actual query a bit cleaner (not so much for this SQL snippet, but for the future).

Comment: Unfortunately SQL has lots of silly non-intuitive corners like that.  Technically subquery shouldn't work either -- a result of subquery is a collection of tuples, not a single number, but it is so convenient to support col = (subquery) that they, I guess, couldn't resist adding support for that.  Doing the same for the tables would be terrible -- at least when looking at a subquery you can say "yes, this will return a single number".  There is no way to force a table to always be a single column single row.  Except when you have subquery factoring.  But that's kind of too much.

Comment: Was joining the only alternative to a subquery before they added subquerying in?  They seem to be part of the standard now.

Comment: Looks like scalar subquery is there in SQL'92 http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any benefit of using **sub-query factoring**(WITH clause) here. The query could simply be written as:

```
SELECT member_id
FROM Enrollments e
WHERE e.enrollment_cost =
  (SELECT MAX (enrollment_cost) FROM Enrollments
  );
```

Compare the explain plans:

**Without sub-query factoring:**

```
SQL> set autot on explain
SQL> SELECT empno FROM emp e WHERE e.sal =
  2    (SELECT MAX (sal) FROM emp
  3    );

     EMPNO
----------
      7839


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1876299339

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |     1 |     8 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL  | EMP  |     1 |     8 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |     4 |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |    56 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("E"."SAL"= (SELECT MAX("SAL") FROM "EMP" "EMP"))
```

**With sub-query factoring:**

```
SQL> WITH max_sal AS
  2    ( SELECT MAX (sal) sal FROM emp
  3    )
  4  SELECT empno FROM emp e WHERE e.sal =
  5    (SELECT sal FROM max_sal
  6    );

     EMPNO
----------
      7839


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 73843676

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |      |     1 |     8 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL   | EMP  |     1 |     8 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   VIEW               |      |     1 |    13 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |     4 |            |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |    56 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("E"."SAL"= (SELECT "SAL" FROM  (SELECT MAX("SAL") "SAL"
              FROM "EMP" "EMP") "MAX_SAL"))
```

See the filter applied, all you are doing is making it nested query and going one level deep without actually adding any benefit.

Comment: Was hoping subquery factoring would help make the code a bit more readable by getting fluff out of the main query.  I guess I was hoping for a local variable for the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your factored query(table) is named `most_expensive` but you use it as column name. In this case you should rather use `keep first`.

```
SELECT max(member_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY enrollment_cost desc nulls last) "Best"
FROM Enrollments e
WHERE e.enrollment_cost = most_expensive;
```